# TDD on iOS vs debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, tdd

I've been lately trying to get into iOS development, so far only watched couple of screencasts (the Stanford series and some other) and they all have one thing in common.

Everyone talks about Instruments and the debugger, but I haven't really seen any TDD or testing at all.

Being a Ruby developer, TDD is basically automatic. I don't even remember the last time I had to use a debugger.

But just from looking at the iOS workflow, where you have to compile the whole app and then load it into the simulator, that makes me thinkg that doing fast TDD won't be as easy.

In my current Ruby workflow, I tend to run my tests every couple of seconds, or at least once a minute. But even in a simple Xcode project it takes at least 30 seconds to compile and run the tests (*MacBook Pro with Core 2 Duo*).

I guess I can't expect the same speed as I get in Ruby, where nothing gets compiled, but this seems like it must be breaking the TDD flow a lot, especially for a bigger project.

**Is it even possible to use TDD or any form of test first development on iOS?**

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do TDD for your apps. See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html) for documentation on it. It talks about how to run unit tests.